# How does Rail's DEVISE gem store temp data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Rails 5 and Devise.

I have a form which can be accessed by anyone. The POST action URL however can only be accessed by signed in users.

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

So if a user is not signed in Devise automatically redirects to the login form, where the user can login or even create a new account. After doing that Devise automatically redirects to the POST URL and the posted data is still available.

So my questions is where in the code of the GEM is Devise handling and storing the redirect URL and POST data.

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/store_location.rb#L18

Comment: What do you mean by `the posted data is still available`? The controller receives the data on the parameters? a form is prefilled with the data? Show your code, the request log, inspect the browser's Network tab too.